# modify this code to make the player move only when the button is held down UNITY 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

When pressing the move button once, the character continues to move without stopping, except when pressing another button
I want to modify this code to make the player move only when the button is held down

```
public void Move(Vector3 velocity, bool standingOnPlatform)
    {
        Move(velocity, Vector2.zero, standingOnPlatform);
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 velocity, Vector2 input, bool standingOnPlatform = false, bool isPlayer = false)
    {

        UpdateRaycastOrigins();
        isBelowOld = collisions.below;

        collisions.Reset();
        collisions.velocityOld = velocity;
        playerInput = input;

        if (velocity.x != 0)
        {
            collisions.faceDir = (int)Mathf.Sign(velocity.x);
        }

        if (velocity.y < 0)
        {
            DescendSlope(ref velocity);
        }

        if (HandlePhysic)
        {
            HorizontalCollisions(ref velocity);
            if (velocity.y != 0)
            {
                VerticalCollisions(ref velocity);
            }
        }

        if (collisions.left || collisions.right)
            velocity.x = 0;

        transform.Translate(velocity, Space.World);

        if (standingOnPlatform)
        {
            collisions.below = true;
        }
    }
```

modify this code to make the player move only when the button is held down

Comment: Why to you have 2 Move function? what calls them? did you try resetting the velocity on every time you call the Move function?